# How to use waze navigation link in mail signature

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, web, gmail

I'm trying to add a link to Waze navigation feature (i.e waze://?q=) to a mail signature but the link is not clickable in most devices. this happens because links on mail must be absolute.
Is there a different form of link which I can use?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `http://waze.to/?ll=<lat>,<long>` if you have coordinates (you can get them using google maps).

example: http://waze.to/?ll=40.758895,-73.985131

Or you can use the query param: `http://waze.to/?q=times+square`

It will open the browser for a split second and will then open waze app.

Comment: Where can I found the source of this?

Comment: https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17684 or https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21642